# tar returning a success status when the disk gets full

Tags: bash, tar

I want to catch the error code when using tar to decompress an Archive.

When I test the status of the tar after running out of space; it throws a successful status.

```
if sudo tar -xf $ARTIFACT_DIR/Deployment_$MODEL_RELEASE.tar.gz --directory $TEMP_DIRECTORY
then
   echo 'Success Decompressing!'
else
   echo 'Failure Decompressing file!'
   exit
fi
```

The bash job, continues as it finds a status of 0.

Comment: I tried this as well; "sudo tar -xf $ARTIFACT_DIR/Deployment_$MODEL_RELEASE.tar.gz --directory $TEMP_DIRECTORY

COMMAND_STATUS=$?
if [ $COMMAND_STATUS != 0 ];then
   echo 'Failure Decompressing file'
   exit
else
   echo 'Success Decompressing'   
fi"

Comment: You can use the "edit" button to complete your answer, it might be clearer then adding a comment

Comment: Mine returns with 2 exit status. Reproduce with: `seq 200000 > /tmp/1 ; tar -cf /tmp/1.tar.gz /tmp/1 ; mkdir -p /tmp/a; sudo mount -o size=1M,noatime -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/a; sudo chown $UID /tmp/a ; tar -xf /tmp/1.tar.gz --directory /tmp/a/` produces `tar: 1: Wrote only 4608 of 10240 bytes` and `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors` and exit status 2. Can't reproduce. Pleasse post tar version. Mine is `tar (GNU tar) 1.32`. Does mine reproducible script in this comment also return with 0 exit status for you? Does `tar` prints anything to stderr?

Comment: Why do you think the disk gets full?

Comment: Linux reserves some fraction of a filesystem space for the root user. However, the `df` tool only displays the free space apparent to regular users.

Comment: What do you see if you add `-v`? (Not sure it will help, just curious.)

Comment: @DaBler, I filled up the directory on purpose to test that it was indeed full. I also ran the command outside of the script and it threw the error of running out of space like what Kamil Cuk got. The issue is when its in a script.

Comment: @kamil Cuk, the version is "tar (GNU tar) 1.26". it throws the error when running just the commands. The issue is when its in a script.

Comment: So this is not related to the disc getting full. Please show the smallest reproducible coded needed to reproduce the problem. Judging from the variables not being inside quotes, there may be many multiple problems with your script not related to the parts you showed in question. Please fix your script with https://www.shellcheck.net/ , before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with the help of $?. (exit status of the previous run command)

Let's take Example to make it clear.

Example1 : (command executed successfully)

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin

# echo $?
0
```

Example2 : (command not executed successfully or no output.)

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep boot

# echo $?
1
```

Find below-corrected script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo tar -xf $ARTIFACT_DIR/Deployment_$MODEL_RELEASE.tar.gz --directory $TEMP_DIRECTORY
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
   echo 'Success Decompressing!'
else
   echo 'Failure Decompressing file!'
   exit
fi
```